# How to retrieve a list data from properties file?

Tags: spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I would like to check if the user entered the country is in the list of properties.

```
public class CountryValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CountryValid,String> {

@Value("#{countryOptions}")
Map<String, String> countryOptions;


@Override
public boolean isValid(String girilenDeger, ConstraintValidatorContext arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        return countryOptions.containsKey(girilenDeger);


}

@Override
public void initialize(CountryValid constraintAnnotation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);

}
```

}

However, I have successfully used this list before in the controller class. I get NullPointerException error when I use it again in my validation class.

```
@Controller@RequestMapping("/customerForm")
```

public class CustomerController {

```
@Value("#{countryOptions}")
Map<String, String> countryOptions;

@RequestMapping("/mainMenu")
public String returnForm(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("theCountryOptions", countryOptions);

    Customer customer1 = new Customer();
    model.addAttribute("customer1", customer1);

    return "customer-view/main-menu";
}

@RequestMapping("/resultPage")
public String returnResult(@Valid @ModelAttribute("customer1") Customer customer, BindingResult result,
        Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("theCountryOptions", countryOptions);


    if (result.hasErrors())
        return "customer-view/main-menu";
    else {

        AddDatabase<Customer> database = new AddDatabase<Customer>();
        database.setObj(customer);
        database.addData();
        System.out.println("Ekleme islemi tamamlandı.");

        return "customer-view/result-page";
    }
}
```

}

Or can I retrieve theCountryOptions attribute from the model?